# PCA for Face Recognition

Tags: pca, reduction, dimensional

Let x1 be a vector(gray) of image1, x2 be a vector(gray) of image2, etc xn be  a vector(gray) of imagen. Say, all the image size is represented by r rows and c columns (r*c)

so, X = [x1, x2, x3, .... xn].

As many literature suggest that, to reduce n. Other literature also prefers to reduce r*c.

Which one to prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will help you to understand how it works and which method to prefer 
http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/nui08/faceRecog.pdf